# postgres function result for in operator

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm using postgres 9.3.
What to return from function to use in "IN" operator?

This is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_lowercase(args text[]) RETURNS TABLE (t text ) AS
  $BODY$
  SELECT btrim(lower(unnest(args)))::text AS tag
  $BODY$
language sql IMMUTABLE;
```

The result is:

```
select array_lowercase(array['  AdaPterKiNd  ','  ResoUrceKinD ']);
 array_lowercase
-----------------
 adapterkind
 resourcekind
(2 rows)
```

But when I'm trying to use the function in "IN" operator it is messaging an error:

```
select * from hd_property where lower(property_name) in (array_lowercase(array['  AdaPterKiNd  ','  ResoUrceKinD ']));
ERROR:  argument of IN must not return a set
LINE 1: select * from hd_property where lower(property_name) in (arr...
                                        ^
```

While the same subquery in "IN" operator (without calling function) is working fine:

```
select * from hd_property where lower(property_name) in ( SELECT btrim(lower(unnest(array['  AdaPterKiNd  ','  ResoUrceKinD '])))::text);
             property_id              | property_name | property_category_id | property_type_id
--------------------------------------+---------------+----------------------+------------------
 aea66c83-fe9f-3729-c3b7-1d000c9866cb | AdapterKind   |                    2 |                1
 cbaf50eb-4b4b-39eb-d769-4737c9715019 | ResourceKind  |                    2 |                1
(2 rows)
```

What to return from function to use in "IN" operator?

Comment: you need subquery for it, like ```select 'subquery' where 'adapterkind' in (select array_lowercase(array['  AdaPterKiNd  ','  ResoUrceKinD ']));
 ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions returning tables have to be used like tables.

```
select * 
from hd_property 
where lower(property_name) in (select t 
                               from array_lowercase(array['  AdaPterKiNd  ','  ResoUrceKinD ']));
```

Comment: This is the only way to use it in IN operator?

Comment: @artos: what else do you need?